# Java: Take multi-line input once

Tags: java, input, user-input

I'm having a bit of a problem with the input in a programming puzzle. I want to convert input into a graph, the input is presented as an unknown amount of lines each having 2 integers separated by a space (this represents the edges). I have searched and not really found an answer, I know how to take input from multiple lines, but then how do I stop after I parsed all the input?

Here's what I mean:

```
Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);
while (stdin.hasNext()) {
        node1 = stdin.nextInt();
        node2 = stdin.nextInt();
        //save edge from node1 to node2
}
//do xyz
```

The problem here is that xyz is never reached and it keeps waiting for input.
Example input would be:

```
0 1
0 3
2 1
```

Comment: Does it always have to be read from 3 lines? Can there be more? How do you know which the last input will be?

Comment: you'll need some symbol like an empty string passed in to get an end of input from a user also you do no checking that you are getting input you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't realize one would have to send an EOF sign (Ctrl+D on Ubuntu/Ctrl+Z on Windows) manually when testing the code, so that's why I posted the question.

When actually reading input from a file or something hasNext() will return false once it reaches the end, so it was just a testing problem.

So just use the shortcuts to send an EOF sign on console and it will make hasNext() return false.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than looping while there is data coming from the Scanner, why not loop until the user signals that they are done adding input with a special character sequence, such as an empty line?

```
Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);
String inputLine = null;
do {
    try {
        inputLine = stdin.nextLine();
        // process the inputLine here!
    } catch (Exception e) {
        break;
    }
} while (inputLine != null && !("".equals(inputLine.trim())));
```